# Filter columns having count equal to the input file rdd Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm filtering Integer columns from the input parquet file with below logic and been trying to modify this logic to add additional validation to see if any one of the input columns have count equals to the input parquet file rdd count. I would want to filter out such column.

**Update**

The number of columns and names in the input file will not be static, it will change every time we get the file.
The objective is to also filter out column for which the count is equal to the input file rdd count. Filtering integer columns is already achieved with below logic.

```
e.g input parquet file count = 100
    count of values in column A in the input file  = 100
```

Filter out any such column.

**Current Logic**

```
 //Get array of structfields

val columns = df.schema.fields.filter(x => 
                x.dataType.typeName.contains("integer"))

  //Get the column names
  val z = df.select(columns.map(x => col(x.name)): _*)

  //Get array of string 
  val m = z.columns
```

**New Logic be like**

```
  val cnt = spark.read.parquet("inputfile").count()

  val d = z.column.where column count is not equals cnt
```

I do not want to pass the column name explicitly to the new condition, since the column having count equal to input file will change ( val d = .. above) 
How do we write logic for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding of your question, your are trying `filter` in columns with `integer` as dataType and whose `distinct count` is not equal to the `count` of `rows` in another input `parquet` file. If my understanding is correct, you can add column count filter in your existing filter as

```
val cnt = spark.read.parquet("inputfile").count()
val columns = df.schema.fields.filter(x =>
  x.dataType.typeName.contains("string") && df.select(x.name).distinct().count() != cnt)
```

Rest of the codes should follow as it is.

I hope the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Jeanr and Ramesh suggested the right approach and here is what I did to get the desired output, it worked :)

```
cnt = (inputfiledf.count())

val r = df.select(df.col("*")).where(df.col("MY_COLUMN_NAME").<(cnt))
```